# Catch response from express to react

Tags: node.js, reactjs

If the password are not matching I am sending a JSON object as a response.
You can see the response in the image below.
I just want this response in my react component in a variable using useState.

```
//Sign Up post Method
router.post('/signup', async (req, res, next) => {

  const { fullname, username, email, dateOfBirth, gender, password, conPassword } = req.body
  const user = new User({ fullname, username, email, dateOfBirth, gender, password })
  if(password !== conPassword) {
    return (
      res.status(400).json({passMatch: "Password are not Matching"})
    )
  }
  try {
    await user.save()
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message)
    res.send(e.message)
  }

})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you are returing a promise. use `.then` method and collect data when the response is 400.

```
const [text,setText] = useState('')
.....
let data = // your request to server
data.then(res=>{
 if(res.status ===400){
setText(res.data)
}
})
```

res.status will return the status of response.
if it is coming as a error use `.catch`

Comment: Nope! I am not getting my JSON error from then. I also tried with catch, catch is giving a built in error

Comment: did you tried `.catch(err=>{ console.log(err.status)  })`

Comment: it says undefind